# Is there a syntax to get the reference to an anonymous inner class from a further anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, syntax, anonymous-inner-class

Consider this case:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        new SomeInterface() {
              public void someOtherMethod() {
                  new SomeOtherInterface() {
                       new someThirdMethod() {
                            //My question is about code located here.
                       }
                  };
              }
        };
    }
}
```

Is there a syntax to reference the instance of the anonymous inner class represented by SomeInterface at the commented code? For SomeClass you can do `SomeClass.this` Is there an equivalent to get the implementation of SomeInterface?

If not, of course you can just define a final local variable in the SomeInterface implementation and reference it, but I was just wondering if there is in fact direct language support to reference the instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why `SomeInterface.this` doesn't compile is because the enclosing class is not `SomeInterface`, but rather some anonymous type.

You can't use qualified `this` with anonymous type. That's why they're *anonymous*; you can't refer to them by name, and qualified `this` works by explicitly naming an enclosing type.

It's tempting to try something like:

```
SomeClass$1.this
```

But then you get an error `SomeClass$1 cannot be resolved to a type`; despite the fact that if you let this code compile without this line, it will (in all likelihood) create a `SomeClass$1.class`.

You can either use a non-anonymous class and use qualified `this`, or you can use the `final` local variable technique you mentioned.

#### References

- [JLS 15.8.4 Qualified `this`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4)