# In Java, access the 'outer object' from inner (class)object?

Tags: java, reflection

There is this way, of course: `OuterClass.this`. But that's very clumsy. Ideally, there'd be a keyword `outer` just like `super`.

Is there some way to do it reflectively? (I have not found any way, the hidden `outer` reference does not seem to show up in the result of `Class#getFields()`.)

Maybe there is a way in Java7?

EDIT. 
Consider this similar question that I just found:

[Is there a syntax to get the reference to an anonymous inner class from a further anonymous inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930327/is-there-a-syntax-to-get-the-reference-to-an-anonymous-inner-class-from-a-furthe?rq=1)

Comment: Do you mean you would prefer to go with a reflection-based solution rather than using OuterClass.this?

Comment: Reflection?  Over `OuterClass.this`?  Do you really expect there's going to be a shorter solution?

Comment: Bit confused by the downvote... is the question unclear? Is it the small bit of opinion I admittedly put in there: "clumsy"?

Comment: @JBNizet, Louis: basically yes (I'd prefer, I'd expect shorter). I often use the PrettyLongName style of naming classes and things. This is mostly a problem for referencing top-level classes/objects, of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way is to use `OuterClass.this` to reference the containing class.

This isn't an issue, if you need to reference the containing class instance more than once, you just assign it to a local variable and you don't have to deal with this syntax more than once. `final OuterClass oc = OuterClass.this;` then you just use `oc` locally to do whatever you need to do.

Having another keyword like `outer` would just obfuscated what was going on. The syntax `OuterClass.this` **explicitly** defines what is going on, a generic keyword would hide the identity of the containing class, especially if it was nested in multiple inner classes. `outer.this.outer.this.outer.this` is hideous!

This isn't a burden by any stretch of the imagination. Especially with modern IDEs.

Comment: Burden or not, there is no sense in supporting a special case of the immediately enclosing instance with a whole new keyword, just to be left with the `qualified this` for all other enclosing instances.

Comment: It could be chained: outer.outer.something. Also, it could instead mean 'the outer context of the current object'. Which would be useful because the 'this' scope in Java seems to always come before the outer scope; which I sometimes find a nuisance, and can also be dangerous: add a new field of the same name anywhere in any class inherited from the current class, and your code might reference that field instead of the outer field/variable.

Comment: @JonasN this has nothing to do with inheritance, your *dangerous* comment is unfounded.

Comment: 'this' has very much to do with inheritance in Java :). Or what don't I understand? Anyway, I'll go verify what I am saying, although I/we're veering somewhat off-topic.

Comment: `       public class Base {
  // protected final int fortytwo = 43;
 }
 
 public void method() {
  final int fortytwo = 42; 
  class Inner extends Base {
   int x = fortytwo;
  }
  
 }

Comment: `this` is an **instance** of a class, it isn't related to inheritance at all. Your straw man is expected behavior and really has nothing to do with `inner` classes at all. What you are worried about isn't *dangerous* because it is expected behavior.

Comment: Didn't get along with the SO comment editor...more readably:
`public class Base {\n
 // protected final int fortytwo = 43;
}

public void method() {
 final int fortytwo = 42; 
 class Inner extends Base {
  int x = fortytwo;
  // uncomment the above comment, and 'fortytwo' turns 43. a outer.fortytwo would help here. or requiring this/self like in Python. 
 } 
}`

Comment: @JonasN see my other comment, this *example* has nothing specific to do with `inner` classes.

Comment: Seems I can't make that code readable here. Anyhow. @Jarrod So any 'expected' behavior of a PL is equally non-dangerous? Why then try to design 'less dangerous' languages by way of trying to reduce surprises? And what do you mean when you say 'this' is an instance of a class and in the same sentence 'not related to inheritance'? The 'this' scope inherits all the public and protected bindings, does it not?

Comment: It was about the 'outer' idea I proposed, which @Marko T then commented on, and thus I felt I wanted to put forward some arguments for a 'outer' construct in Java, that it could make the use of inner classes less, my word only, dangerous. Someone adding or removing a declaration in a class definition derived from _can_ change the meaning of the code I see in the inner class.

Answer (score -1):

### Please try this code which does exactly what you wanted:

```
                Object innerClassInstance = null; //get an inner class instance from somewhere.

                Object outerClassInstance = null;
                Field[] fields = innerClassInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    String name = field.getName();
                    Object value = field.get(innerClassInstance);
                    if ("this$0".equals(name) && value != null) {
                        outerClassInstance = value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (outerClassInstance != null) {
                    // now do something with your outer class instance
                }
```

---